# Linux TCP connection establishment is very slow

Tags: linux, networking

I'm not sure what's wrong, but every outgoing network connection is very slow on my server (called dikkenek in the snippets below). It seems it's at the connection establishment.

```
bicou@dikkenek:~$ time ping -c 1 free.fr
PING free.fr (212.27.48.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from www.free.fr (212.27.48.10): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=12.1 ms

--- free.fr ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.185/12.185/12.185/0.000 ms

real    0m10.025s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

As you can see the connection is perfectly fine (12ms to my ISP home page), however it took 10 seconds to run the ping.

Pinging directly the IP is much faster:

```
bicou@dikkenek:~$ time ping -c 1 212.27.48.10
PING 212.27.48.10 (212.27.48.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 212.27.48.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=12.0 ms

--- 212.27.48.10 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.045/12.045/12.045/0.000 ms

real    0m0.013s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

So I thought I had a name resolution issue, but it's fast too:

```
bicou@dikkenek:~$ time host free.fr
free.fr has address 212.27.48.10
free.fr has IPv6 address 2a01:e0c:1::1
free.fr mail is handled by 20 mx2.free.fr.
free.fr mail is handled by 10 mx1.free.fr.

real    0m3.022s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.000s
```

OK, it took 3 seconds, but that's not longer than a fast machine, see below.

As a comparison, here are the same commands ran on my laptop (Mac OS X):

```
<9> Mon May 11 23:05:42 ~ $ time ping -c 1 free.fr
PING free.fr (212.27.48.10): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 212.27.48.10: icmp_seq=0 ttl=58 time=15.194 ms

--- free.fr ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 15.194/15.194/15.194/0.000 ms

real    0m0.026s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.003s
<10> Mon May 11 23:05:48 ~ $ time ping -c 1 212.27.48.10
PING 212.27.48.10 (212.27.48.10): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 212.27.48.10: icmp_seq=0 ttl=58 time=44.084 ms

--- 212.27.48.10 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 44.084/44.084/44.084/0.000 ms

real    0m0.060s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.003s
<11> Mon May 11 23:06:09 ~ $ time host free.fr
free.fr has address 212.27.48.10
free.fr has IPv6 address 2a01:e0c:1::1
free.fr mail is handled by 20 mx2.free.fr.
free.fr mail is handled by 10 mx1.free.fr.

real    0m3.059s
user    0m0.006s
sys     0m0.006s
```

The ping is much faster.

Simple HTTP connections are very slow too:

```
bicou@dikkenek:~$ time curl -sI 'free.fr'
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 11 May 2015 21:10:47 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 154
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://portail.free.fr/


real    0m5.548s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.000s
```

My laptop:

```
<14> Mon May 11 23:08:11 ~ $ time curl -sI 'free.fr'
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 11 May 2015 21:12:04 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 154
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://portail.free.fr/


real    0m0.043s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.004s
```

An iperf between the two (both ways) is perfectly fine:

```
bicou@dikkenek:~$ iperf -c 192.168.0.13 -r
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.0.13, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  5] local 192.168.0.10 port 55416 connected with 192.168.0.13 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]  0.0-10.2 sec  8.50 MBytes  7.01 Mbits/sec
[  4] local 192.168.0.10 port 5001 connected with 192.168.0.13 port 55140
[  4]  0.0-10.4 sec  16.4 MBytes  13.3 Mbits/sec
```

The throughput is not that great because the laptop is connected over WiFi only. The server is connected to the router using a 1Gbps ethernet cable.

iperf to the outside world works as advertised (ISP says 1.1Mbps UL / 31.5Mbps DL):

```
bicou@dikkenek:~$ iperf -c iperf.testdebit.info -r
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to iperf.testdebit.info, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.0.10 port 37395 connected with 89.84.127.54 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-11.0 sec  1.88 MBytes  1.43 Mbits/sec
[  5] local 192.168.0.10 port 5001 connected with 89.84.127.54 port 33129
[  5]  0.0-10.2 sec  30.4 MBytes  24.9 Mbits/sec
```

My main concern is http slowness, which is almost always 5.5 seconds late.

The server runs Debian 8 jessie, the laptop runs Mac OS X.10 Yosemite.

What tools can I use to troubleshoot the Debian slowness?

---

Edit: as Otheus pointed out, it's likely a DNS issue. Here's a test that confirms it:

```
bicou@dikkenek:~$ time curl -sIH 'Host: free.fr' 212.27.48.10
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 11 May 2015 21:57:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 154
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://portail.free.fr/


real    0m0.034s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Now how can I speed things up here?

Comment: I think DNS is your main problem. Is ``HostnameLookups`` enabled in http's configuration?

Comment: You're right. `curl -sIH 'Host: free.fr' 212.27.48.10` runs instantly (40ms). Where is that `HostnameLookups`?

Comment: I'm not a Debian guru, but typically it's going to be in ``/etc/http/httpd.conf ``... or maybe ``/etc/http/conf/httpd.conf``. If the web server is ``*nginx``, then I doubt that's the problem.

Comment: The http server is from my ISP, I don't have access to it. The issue is when my Debian machine tries to connect to any web server.

Comment: See if it accepts ``/server-status`` as a URI

Comment: Ah nevermind, I see this is probably the wrong idea. I thought the HTTP server *was* your server.

Comment: What server hosts the authoritative DNS answer for your server? Is it perhaps your server?

Comment: You nailed it! I had a bogus server on the first line of `/etc/resolv.conf`. Removing it fixed the issue! Thanks! (post an answer I'll accept it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your DNS config is messed up. Check your `/etc/resolv.conf` and ensure that only valid servers are listed.